# Modal window Cocoa app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, osx-snow-leopard

I just recently started making apps for OSX desktops and I want to have the users click a button and a window come up, similar to the following screenshots. What is that window that comes up called? You can't quit the application when you're entering the information. I tried looking for ways to make an NSAlert do this, but I was way off. Can someone please point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The common name for what's shown in those images is a "sheet".

Technically, this is generally accomplished using 2 `NSWindow`s (or `NSPanel`s), one of which is termed the sheet, and which is shown modally against the second window, which serves as the main window the sheet appears from.

See [Sheet Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Sheets/Sheets.html).

While I believe you can use `NSAlert`'s for displaying simple dialogs in this fashion, the setup shown in those images was most likely accomplished by using a custom sheet. See [Using Custom Sheets](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Sheets/Tasks/UsingCustomSheets.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001290-BABFIBIA).

Answer (score 0):

Its called a Modal Window or Modal Dialog or Sheet.

There are two types, 'Application Modal' and 'Sheets'.

Comment: And in general, you should avoid Application Modal windows where at all possible. In the example shown, a sheet is much more appropriate.